# scanf giving random behaviour

Tags: c, scanf

Can someone explain me the working of scanf. If i am entering s as integer it would work fine but i enter a character it would run continuously till it exits the loop. So it is not removing the character from the buffer and not asking for input. Can you provide more insight on scanf and it's internal implementation

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int s,i = 0;
   while(i < 10)
   {
     scanf("%d",&s);
     i++;
    printf("%d",s);

   }

  while(i < 20)
  {
    printf("%d",s);
    scanf("%c",&s); 
  }

}
```

Comment: I think you're being confounded by several things: no increment in the second loop; different order of printf and scanf in the second loop; reading  a number in the first loop (which also eats the newline) vs reading a character in the second loop (which doesn't eat the newline, so you'll read that separately as well). Can you try to simplify things further, provide your real output, and state your expected output?

Comment: Always, *always* check return value of `scanf` (check what it means, if you don't know).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%c`specifier is for characters not for `int` data types. Using wrong format specifier for a data type invoke undefined behavior.

Also note that `i` is not incrementing in the second loop. This will lead to an infinite `while` loop.

Comment: can you explain me the internals of scanf

Comment: You can read some tutorial for c input/outputs functions. There you can find the details about data types and their corresponding format specifiers.